# What does Aristotle mean by contemplation?

Tags: aristotle

In Nicomachean Ethics Aristotle writes about contemplation and it being a kind of good of mankind, an ultimate good etc. But what actually is contemplation? What would be a good example of contemplation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Greek word for contemplation is 'theoria', and is the basis for the word 'theory' where it came to mean 'careful contemplation of a subject'. A theoros is a spectator at a theatre, observing the drama without involving themselves in it. It's interesting to note in his Poetics Aristotle is said to have defined the modern meaning of 'catharsis' (it used to mean a kind purging of sins), so it's reasonable to think his advocacy for non-involvement didn't mean to be completely unfeeling.

In the Nichomachean Ethics he describes the life of contemplation as being of the highest virtue, and best source of happiness:

> "the Working of the Intellect, being apt for contemplation, is thought
> to excel in earnestness, and to aim at no End beyond itself and to
> have Pleasure of its own which helps to increase the Working, and if
> the attributes of Self-Sufficiency, and capacity of rest, and
> unweariedness (as far as is compatible with the infirmity of human
> nature), and all other attributes of the highest Happiness, plainly
> belong to this Working, this must be perfect Happiness"

And as most akin to the nature of the gods:

> "And that the perfect Happiness must be a kind of Contemplative
> Working may appear also from the following consideration: our
> conception of the gods is that they are above all blessed and happy:
> now what kind of Moral actions are we to attribute to them? those of
> justice? nay, will they not be set in a ridiculous light if
> represented as forming contracts, and restoring deposits, and so on?
> well then, shall we picture them performing brave actions,
> withstanding objects of fear and meeting dangers, because it is noble
> to do so? or liberal ones? but to whom shall they be giving? and
> further, it is absurd to think they have money or anything of the
> kind. And as for actions of perfected self-mastery, what can theirs
> be? would it not be a degrading praise that they have no bad desires?
> In short, if one followed the subject into all details all the
> circumstances connected with Moral actions would appear trivial and
> unworthy of Gods.
>
> Still, every one believes that they live, and therefore that they Work
> because it is not supposed that they sleep their time away like
> Endymion: now if from a living being you take away Action, still more
> if Creation, what remains but Contemplation?"

So he seems to advocate a kind of ascent, away from entanglement with ordinary affairs, towards the highest qualities of being human which is the divine part it connects to what is transcendental.

Comment: You could see the 'Working' as similar to the 'wellbeing' which is the keyword of the modern Nonduality movement.